# Equation of circle through 3 non collinear complex points.

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

My attempt to find the equation of circle
For $4$ given complex points $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ to be concyclic The complex number given by
$$\frac{(z_3-z_1)(z_4-z_2)}{(z_3-z_2)(z_4-z_1)}\ \text{must be real}$$

I replaced one from $z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4$ by variable $z$. Then condition for these points to be concyclic (so that locus of point $z$ would give a circle in complex plane) is

The complex number $$\frac{(z-z_2)(z_3-z_1)}{(z-z_1)(z_3-z_2)}\ \text{must be purely real}$$

I don't know what to do next.

In my book final answer is given as

$$\frac{(z-z_2)(z_3-z_1)}{(z-z_1)(z_3-z_2)} = \frac{(\overline{z}-\overline{z}_2)(\overline{z}_3-\overline{z}_1)}{(\overline{z}-\overline{z}_1)(\overline{z}_3-\overline{z}_2)}$$

Comment: I think you might have some issue in the first equation. I see $(z_3-z_1)$ both at numerator and denominator, so I can simplify the expression, and you have no $z_3$ dependence

Comment: I see, I have corrected the equation now

Comment: You've quite done. Realize that a number $a \in \mathbb{C}, a \neq  0$ is real iff $Arg(a)=k\pi,\,k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ Thus the equation of the circle is $Arg \frac{(z-z_2)(z_3-z_1)}{(z-z_1)(z_3-z_2)} =k \pi$ or $z=z_2$ or $z=z_1.$

Comment: If I choose $z_1=1$, $z_2=i$, $z_3=-1$, $z_4=-i$ (4 points on the unit circle), the above expression is not real

Comment: The right-hand side is simply the complex conjugate of the left-hand side (and a number is purely real if and only if it is equal to its complex conjugate).

Comment: Andrei the points cannot be arbitrarily taken. The equation I uploaded is a generalized one for points taken in order $z_1,z_3,z_2,z_4$ either clockwise or counterclockwise. Apologies for not uploading figure with question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate the equation of a circle given 3 complex numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/how-do-i-calculate-the-equation-of-a-circle-given-3-complex-numbers)