# Simplify $Im \left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

Let $z \in \mathbb{H}$, where $\mathbb{H}$ denotes the [half plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)) $\mathbb{H}=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:Im(z)>0\}$. Let
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}
\end{equation*}
which is called a [Mobius Transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation), and let $ad-bc>0$. I want to show that $Im(f(z))>0$.

---

Following [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/454998/100167), I should use $Im(z)=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$. Applying this formula, I get
\begin{align*}
Im (f(z))
&=Im \left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) \\
&=\frac{\frac{az+b}{cz+d}-\overline{\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)}}{2i}
\end{align*}
but I am not sure how to show that this equals $\frac{ad-bc}{c^2+d^2}$. Is there a nice and clean way to simplify $Im(f(z))$? Thank you!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36542/real-and-imaginary-parts-of-the-m%C3%B6bius-transformation

Comment: That looks really messy. I'm surprised how the solution I linked to concluded so easily that $\textrm{Im}(f(z)) = \frac{ad-bc}{c^2+d^2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an error in the answer you linked. We cannot expect $Im (f(z))$ not to depend on $z$; otherwise, $f$ would map $\mathbb{H}$ to an horizontal line, which contradicts its analyticity.

I think the best way is to multiply by the conjugate of the denominator:

$$Im \left( \frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right) = Im \left( \frac{(az+b)(c \overline{z}+d)}{(cz+d)(c \overline{z}+d)}\right) = \frac{1}{|cz+d|^2} Im \left( acz\overline{z}+bc\overline{z}+adz+bd\right) = \frac{(ad-bc) Im(z)}{|cz+d|^2}.$$

Comment: Ah, I see it now! Very well explained! Thank you!

Comment: @Ethanalvaree yes, it was a simple omission on my part. Feel free to edit it into my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d}=\frac{(az+b)(c\bar{z}+d)}{|cz+d|^2}$$

And one has

$$(az+b)(c\bar{z}+d)=acz\bar{z}+adz+bc\bar{z}+bd$$

$acz\bar{z}+bd$ is real and $\mathcal{I}(adz+bc\bar{z})=(ad-bc)\mathcal{I}(z)$

Putting the above together, one gets

$$\mathcal{I}\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)=\frac{ad-bc}{|cz+d|^2}\mathcal{I}(z)$$

Comment: Very helpful answer Marwalix. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure